# Apache Tomcat not working after downloading jre v8

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have recently ran into an issue with Apache Tomcat 7. I had Java JRE v7 installed. Then, after I updated to JRE v8, my server fails. I noticed that jre7 was removed upon install of v8, so I reinstalled v7, and Tomcat is still not working properly.

Below is the console output I received. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

```
    Sep 09, 2015 7:03:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (21, 76) : org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
Sep 09, 2015 7:03:53 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1276)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1537)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:679)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:456)

Sep 09, 2015 7:03:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: Error at (21, 76) : org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
Sep 09, 2015 7:03:53 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: Cannot start server. Server instance is not configured.
```

Comment: The tomcat server in my company doesn't work too someday. And i found HERE and [that post](https://communities.bmc.com/thread/105809?start=0&tstart=0).

Answer (score 1):

I believe tomcat 7 does not run in JRE version 8. You can use different version of tomcat if you want to use Java version 8. For version 7 you can remove the server from eclipse and then add tomcat 7 again as your server.